# Dual boot problem, separate usb sdd on legacy bios

Tags: dual-boot

I have win10 on a 2006 acer desktop. Legacy bios.
I connected a clean sdd to a usb port and i want to put the latest ubuntu on it.
Install happens from flash drive containing image, all goes well, disk partitioning, etc... but after restart no option to boot into ubuntu, just starts win 10.
If i select usb in the bios to boot up, i get a black screen with a blinking cursor.
What am i missing to make ubuntu run?

Comment: There is a "choose bootloader install destination" menu in Ubuntu when the disk is partitioned. Where did you put the bootloader?

Comment: Newer Acer require you to enable "trust" on Ubuntu UEFI entry. But a 2006 system would be BIOS only using MBR to boot. Did you install grub to MBR to sdd? Default is normally first drive. I found an external SSD worked much better with my old 2006 Toshiba laptop. Full Ubuntu would not work as system had too little RAM. Kubuntu did work ok. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors)